# Make second connection to external DB

Tags: database, zend-framework, frameworks

I use classic connecion, which created in bootstap by read parameters from application.ini file. I would like use more external DBs, but I can´t read them from application.ini. I prefer read parameters from main DB (which external DB it is, depend on website). So how effectivelly make connection in model? Now I set that connection every time when I need use it. And when I need use main DB, is neccessary make connection again. It´s very uneffective solution.

```
function joinClientDB($id)
{
    $web = $this->getById($id);
    $dbSettings = array();
    $dbSettings['host'] = $web['web_dbHost'];
    $dbSettings['username'] = $web['web_dbUsername'];
    $dbSettings['password'] = $web['web_dbPassword'];
    $dbSettings['dbname'] = $web['web_dbName'];
    $this->_db = Zend_Db::factory('pdo_mysql', $dbSettings);
    $this->_db->query('SET CHARACTER SET ' . $web['web_dbCharset']);
}

function joinDefaultDb()
{
    $this->_db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
}
```

Has anybody easy solution for me?

Comment: it Looks like your configuration is going to allow for an unlimited number of db connection configurations. With that kind of architecture your options with what ZF can do are going to be limited. The best you can probably hope for is to build a plugin that registers the correct DB parameters with every request.

Comment: Teoretically yes but practically no. I need to connections, first main (which I load with params from application.ini) and second additional, which params I have to obtain from that main DB. Ideally I will make singleton in first obtain params with an appropriate model. I don´t know if is it good solution. How on that solution with plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the Zend MULTI DB Plugin. Add to your applications.ini all database connections:

```
; Database ONE
resources.multidb.test.adapter = 
resources.multidb.test.dbname = 
resources.multidb.test.username = 
resources.multidb.test.password = ""
resources.multidb.test.host = "your.local.host"
resources.multidb.test.default = true

; Database TWO
resources.multidb.live.adapter = 
resources.multidb.live.dbname = 
resources.multidb.live.username = 
resources.multidb.live.password = ""
resources.multidb.live.host = "your.live.host.com"
```

And now you could put them in your registry again (bootstrap.php):

```
protected function _initDbAdapters()
{
    $this->bootstrap('multidb');
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    $resource>init();

    $testDB = $resource->getDb('test');
    $liveDB = $resource->getDb('live'); 

    Zend_Registry::set('DB_TEST', $testDB);
    Zend_Registry::set('DB_LIVE', $liveDB);
}
```

Comment: I need second DB (external one) connect with parameters which are stored in main DB (is wrote it above).